# Sum Function with Index/Match Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have to prepare summary sheet for the expenses, claimed by employees.

What I need from this summary:

Different expenses claimed by employees month-on-month.  I've a sheet named as 'Dataentry' where I add all the expense claimed. I've tried  Index/Match function with Sum but failing to do so. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7qw9.png)

```
=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX('Dataentry'!$D$4:$I$19,MATCH(A6,'Dataentry'!$C$4:$C$19,0),MATCH($D$3,'Data entry'!$D$3:$I$3,0)),0),0)
```

Link to my excel sheet: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtZjyXgtSauegbc09Fwyfi56NKX-4w

Can somebody help me.

Comment: With index/match/match your table and column references must include the header row, so your formula should be =SUM(IFERROR(INDEX('Data entry'!$D$3:$I$19,MATCH(A6,'Data entry'!$C$3:$C$19,0),MATCH($D$3,'Data entry'!$D$3:$I$3,0)),0),0)

Comment: Hey David!
Tried this. Didn't work.

Comment: @DivyanshuPathak, nothing wrong with your formula, it's getting the correct value from Telephone Column for the moth of May,,is 4000. check the Dataentry Sheet. What you are trying to do ? Just write us !!

Comment: I guess you are trying to get SUM of `MAY` for `TELEPHONE` column write ? Are you looking for `16550` ?

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Yes I'm trying to sum the amount of Telephone for all the claims in the month of May which is 16550. But the solution that you mentioned below gives me #N/A Error. The changes that you made in the sheet I shared are not showing, can you please make the changes again and save the file. It would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Write this formula in **Sheet Reco** in cell **Q4 then fill Right & down:**

```
=SUM(INDEX((Dataentry!$B$3:$H$3=Q$3)*(Dataentry!$C$4:$C$19=$P4)*Dataentry!E$4:E$19,))
```

**N.B.**

- *I've calculate Sum of 3 months & two articles, you may modify this.*
- Adjust cell references in formula as needed.

Comment: Tried this. Copied the formula you mentioned above, but it's adding up the expenses. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: @DivyanshuPathak, check the formula carefully and I've used your sheet only to solve it, it's working or check my profile and send me text mail, I'll mail back your WB with solved formula. Meanwhile if you wish you can Select it as answer or up vote.